# Parse Pointer Permissions don't allow create

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

I've followed every step of [this walkthrough](http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-from-the-data-browser-with-pointer-permissions/), but when I try to create a new row, I get a 403:

> code: 119
>
> message: "This user is not allowed to perform the create
> operation on Messages. You can change this setting in the Data Browser."

My code:

```js
Messages = Parse.Object.extend("Messages")
var message = new Messages();
message.set("sender", Parse.User.current());
message.set("receiver", *anotherUser*);
message.set("subject", "foo")
message.set("body", "bar")
message.save()
.then(
  function(message){
    console.log("success!")
  },function(error){
    console.log("error: ", error);
});
```

My CLPs are set as follows:
[image]
[image]

It looks like someone else posted [the same issue in a google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/eAiaklfKAtg). What are we missing?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the what the value is of `Parse.User.current()`? My guess is that it's returning a nil user. Also, I've always used `PFUser.currentUser()`, so maybe give that a go too

Comment: Just double-checked–I `console.log` it out just before I save it, and it is a valid user object with an id.

Comment: Is it different from `request.user`? Try logging that too to see if they are different

Comment: They're the same. Just modified my cloudcode as requested and see in my logs, `before_save triggered for Messages for user xxxx`, where `xxxx` is the same as the `sender` field.

Comment: @Russell have you ever used pointer permissions and had `create` work as expected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've submitted this as [a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/437980593072642/) to Parse (Facebook), and they replied:

> We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team.

I will update this answer once the issue has been resolved. **If this issue is impacting you, please subscribe to the bug, as this will help prioritize the fix.**

### UPDATE

Facebook replied:

> Turns out that this is actually by design. To create an object, the class should have public create permissions on it

Unfortunately, with this solution, I can create a message "from" any other user (another user set as the `sender`). This is unacceptable and unusable IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

That has been a bug since the launch of Pointer Permissions, which effectively makes them useless. My impression is they built this with the idea of letting developers secure existing schemas in one go, but of course you need it to work for future creation.

One workaround would involve combining the older Class Level Permissions and  per-row ACL's while being careful to not disable your Data Browser. Let's assume you have classes "Puppy" and "Cat" and both have a field called "owner".

1. In your Data Browser, for each class where it makes sense to have an owner field, you set its Class Level Permissions for Puppy and Cat each to:

**Public** -      Read: Yes or No, depends on your use case,  Write: Yes

**Add a Pointer Permission for "owner"** -   Read: Yes, Write: Yes (can skip this for now, see below)

2. Then in your cloud/main.js, you can use the following as a starting point (which I often call "types" below, sorry).
3. When Parse fixes the creation issue, you remove the Public Write Class Level permission (above), leave the Pointer Permission one, and get rid of the workaround code below.

--

```
var validateAndUpdateOwnerWritePerms = function(request){
    var object = request.object;
    var error = null;
    var owner = object.get('owner');

    if (!Parse.User.current()) {
        error = 'User session required to create or modify object.';
    } else if (!owner) {
        error = 'Owner expected, but not found.';
    } else if (owner && owner.id != Parse.User.current().id && !object.existed()) {
        error = 'User session must match the owner field in the new object.';
    }

    if (request.master) {
        error = null;
    }

    if (error) {
        return error;
    }

    if (object.existed()) {
        return null;
    }

    var acl = new Parse.ACL();
    acl.setReadAccess(owner, true);
    acl.setWriteAccess(owner, true);

    object.setACL(acl);

    return null;
}

// Wrapper that makes beforeSave, beforeDelete, etc. respect master-key calls.
// If you use one of those hooks directly, your tests or admin
// console may not work.
var adminWriteHook = function(cloudHook, dataType, callback) {
    cloudHook(dataType, function(request, response) {
        if (request.master) {
            Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        } else {
            var noUserAllowed = false;
            if (cloudHook == Parse.Cloud.beforeSave &&
                (dataType == Parse.Installation || dataType == Parse.User)) {
                    noUserAllowed = true;
            }
            if (!noUserAllowed && !Parse.User.current()) {
                response.error('Neither user session, nor master key was found.');
                return null;
            }
        }

        return callback(request, response);
    });
};

// Set hooks for permission checks to run on delete and save.
var beforeOwnedTypeWriteHook = function(type) {
    var callback = function (request, response) {
        var error = validateAndUpdateOwnerWritePerms(request);
        if (error) {
            response.error(error);
            return;
        }
        response.success();
    };
    return adminWriteHook(Parse.Cloud.beforeSave, type, callback);
    return adminWriteHook(Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete, type, callback);
};

beforeOwnedTypeWriteHook('Puppy');
beforeOwnedTypeWriteHook('Cat');
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems that Parse Pointer Permissions do not work as you expect it on `Create`. The quick fix would be to allow `Create` permission to Public. Then to ensure that the user who is creating a record is the same as the `sender`. So you need to perform a manual check in the `beforeSave` trigger for `Messages` class in cloud code and if that check fails, reject the record being created.

Comment: Good idea about utilizing cloud code but it's always best to use CLPs and ACLs where possible. Since the current user of the app is creating the message object, there shouldn't be any issues. My guess is that there is an error with `Parse.User.current()` returning nil

Comment: What does granting `create` permission do then?

Comment: @Russell As I said pointer permissions unfortunately somehow do not work when sender is creating a record. You need to grant create permissions without them @@adamdport By granting Create permission you let anyone create a record in that class. Add the simple cloud code logic and now only the Sender will be able to create a record. Problem solved as you get the expected behaviour

Comment: @MoNazemi I meant what does `create` do as a pointer CLP, not public. I have no doubts that I could manage these permissions manually through Cloud Code, but I'd like to leverage Parse's OTC solutions whenever possible.

Comment: Sadly it does nothing !! Create does not seems to work at all. The workaround given is the only way around it as far as I know. This to me should be reported as a bug to Parse.

Comment: Agreed about reporting this as a bug. This seems like an oversight on Parse's end